# How to load my custom adapter configuration properties in BizTalk 2020 in property browser using IAdapterConfig?

Tags: adapter, biztalk, biztalk-2020, getschema

I have a custom Adapter in BizTalk 2020 that reads data from MongoDB GridFS. But since the code was earlier in 2013 R2 Framework, now while migrating it to 2020 Framework, it throws error like

> IAdapterInterface is not implemented

I then added this `Microsoft.Adapter.Biztalk.AdapterFramework` namespace in my projects so now I inherited the `IAdapterInterface`.

But How do I implement its `methods(GetConfigSchema()` and `GetSchema()` to load the Receive handler/send handler/ schema in property browser in admin console?

Answer (score 0):

**GetConfigSchema()**
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/adapter-configuration-schemas to get an idea of setting the config name, default value and creating a "drop-down" of values to choose from.

**GetSchema()**
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/adapter-getschema-method on explanation when you need to return null or an actual schema.